# Android create contact from class extending AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use code from developers.android.com to create a contact

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
      new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

 int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
      .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
      .build());

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
      .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan")
      .build());

 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

It works well when done from Activity, but I want to do it from a class, which extends AsyncTask. I did some research and ended up with conclusion, I need to pass somehow the context (because simple getActivity() won't work), so I can          context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
but unfortunately no idea how to do it in my case

Comment: What about passing the activity through constructor of AsyncTask custom class ? and save it as a global variable to be used?

Answer (score 0):

**This is how to pass Context to AsyncTask class:**

`new CreateContact().execute(getActivity());` in Fragment

or in Activity `new CreateContact().execute(getApplicationContext());`

```
public class CreateContact extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
    Context  mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();}

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... param) {
        mContext=param[0];
        try {
          //your code.....              
          mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
        //your code.....
    }
}
```

or you can pass the context to the construct